# Turn link into image "button"

Tags: css

I would like to remove the text in a link and replace it with an image using css.

Markup:

```
<a id="notifications" href="#">Notifications</a>
```

Css:

```
#notifications{
    background: url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/treetog/i/16/Floppy-Small-icon.png') no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MsG6A/).

I have tried all sorts of things, but can't seem to get rid of the text. Is this something that is not doable with css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As minaz pointed out, `display: block` will solve the issue.  These other properties will also get your `<a>`, which is a `display: inline` element by default, to respect the `text-indent` property:

```
float: left|right;
position: absolute;
display: inline-block;
```

The W3 spec on [text-indent](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#indentation-prop) explains why:

> This property specifies the indentation of the first line of text in a
>   block container. More precisely, it specifies the indentation of the
>   first box that flows into the block's first line box.

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the display property:

```
display:block;
```